# Which is the X display driver for the AMD Radeon HD series in 12.04?

Tags: drivers, ati, open-source

I'm looking for the AMD open source drivers for the HD series like my HD6250, but i can't find this drivers in the official repository, this package `xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd` is simply not available in the repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core open-source graphics driver is bundled by default as part of the kernel (`radeon`). You shouldn't need to separately install it.

The X display driver `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and userspace DRM driver `libdrm-radeon` should normally be auto-installed, but may be manually installed via `apt-get` if needed.

Comment: you mean `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` or `libdrm-radeon1` ?

Comment: @user827992: both, please see edited answer.